# Italian coin collector

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   3. Extraordinary claim: He is 13 across after 9 down (7)
>   6. Crashed ashore, sounding rough (6)
>   8. Got away from David and Edward going separate ways (6)
>   10. General supermarket chain from Germany follows Italy's #1 in fashion (9)
>   12. Rights to incorporate a compression format (3, abbr.)
>   13. Crime lord's small gesture backed by inner circle controlling Mexican city (3,8)
>   16. One soldier enters – voilà, America becomes prominent (11)
>   20. Hot liquid and endless vapour (3)
>   21. 1 down author's unfinished opus and final letter acquired by Italian coin collector (5,4)
>   24. Someone who makes the cut tied or undone (6)
>   25. Get on top of Everest to indicate having extreme backbone (6)
>   26. Police officer pursuing organization leaders backing Capone, leading to man behind 1 down (7)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Readaptation of  *The Frog* – hated film based on beloved book (3,9)
>   2. Snoop at Ronald's secret supporter (6)
>   3. Self-referential part of statement brought up (4)
>   4. Number two mostly returned as indicated (4)
>   5. Brave conclusion against final bits of pressure (6)
>   7. Records mention small streams but no river (7,5)
>   9. 1 down's right to reject broadcast (4)
>   11. Controversial novel's first half leads to joyful reaction (3, abbr.)
>   14. Slavic state from south of Spain northward (3)
>   15. Jewish priest: "God goes before me." (3)
>   16. 3 across actor seen as Tupac in Oscar-winning part (6)
>   17. Monster's ball under a tree (4)
>   18. Dark matter among stardust (3)
>   19. Jocularly keeping seen with the eye (6)
>   22. Go underneath a river's bottom to get ship (4)
>   23. Thought had by Luigi de Amato (4)

Comment: I can't see the grid. Why tag "cryptic-crosswords"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"I'll make them a crossword they can't resist!"

Across

> ```
>  3. Extraordinary claim: He is 13 across after 9 down (7)   MICHAEL = (CLAIM HE)*
>  6. Crashed ashore, sounding rough (6)                      HOARSE = ASHORE*
>  8. Got away from David and Edward going separate ways (6)  EVADED = DAVE< + ED
> 10. General supermarket chain from Germany follows          GARIBALDI = GAR(I)B + ALDI
>     Italy's #1 in fashion (9)
> 12. Rights to incorporate a compression format (3)          RAR = R(A)R
> 13. Crime lord's small gesture backed by inner circle       DON CORLEONE
>     controlling Mexican city (3,8)                              = NOD< + COR(LEON)E
> 16. One soldier enters -- voilà, America becomes prominent  PRESTIGIOUS = PREST(I GI)O + US
> 20. Hot liquid and endless vapour (3)                       TEA = (s)TEA(m)
> 21. 1 down author's unfinished opus and final letter        MARIO PUZO
>                                                                 = (OPU(s) + Z) in MARIO
>     acquired by Italian coin collector (5,4)
> 24. Someone who makes the cut tied or undone (6)            EDITOR = (TIED OR)*
> 25. Get on top of Everest to indicate having extreme        EMBARK = E... + M(B)ARK 
>     backbone (6)
> 26. Police officer pursuing organization leaders backing     COPPOLA = COP + P... O... + AL<
>     Capone, leading to man behind 1 down (7)
> ```

Down

> ```
>  1. Readaptation of The Frog -- hated film based on         THE GODFATHER
>     beloved book (3,9)                                          = (THE FROG HATED)*
>  2. Snoop at Ronald's secret supporter (6)                  PATRON = snoo_P AT RON_ald's
>  3. Self-referential part of statement brought up (4)       META = st_ATEM<_ent
>  4. Number two mostly returned as indicated (4)             CUED = DEUC(e) <
>  5. Brave conclusion against final bits of pressure (6)     ENDURE = END + (press)URE
>  7. Records mention small streams but no river (7,5)        ADDRESS BOOKS
>                                                                 = ADDRESS + B(r)OOKS
>  9. 1 down's right to reject broadcast (4)                  VITO = sound like VETO (@w l)
> 11. Controversial novel's first half leads to joyful        LOL = LOL(ita)
>     reaction (3)
> 14. Slavic state from south of France northward (3)         RUS = SUR<
> 15. Jewish priest: "God goes before me." (3)                ELI = EL + I
> 16. 3 across actor seen as Tupac in Oscar-winning part      PACINO = Tu_PAC IN O_scar
> 17. Monster's ball under a tree (4)                         ELMO = ELM + O
> 18. Dark matter among stardust (3)                          TAR = s_TAR_dust
> 19. Jocularly keeping seen with the eye (6)                 OCULAR = j_OCULAR_ly
> 22. Go underneath a river's bottom to get ship (4)          ARGO = A (rive)R + GO
> 23. Thought had by Luigi de Amato (4)                       IDEA = luig_I DE A_mato
> ```

The grid

> ```
>      T   P     M I C H A E L
>      H O A R S E   U     N   A
>      E   T     T   E V A D E D
>      G A R I B A L D I   U   D
>      O   O       O   T   R A R
>      D O N C O R L E O N E   E
>      F         U   L         S
>      A   P R E S T I G I O U S
>      T E A   L   A       C   B
>      H   C   M A R C O P U Z O
>      E D I T O R   D     L   O
>      R   N     G   E M B A R K
>        C O P P O L A     R   S
> ```

The theme

> If it wasn't obvious, the theme is [*The Godfather*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather) (1d) written by Mario Puzo (21) and made into a film by Francis Ford Coppola (26). Many more clues reference the work.

Comment: I think the wordplay part of 9d is: homophone of "right to reject".

Comment: @wl: Ah, homophones, my soft spot. Thanks.

Comment: Not getting 14D!  South of France would be ROT13(FHQ) not ROT13(FHE).   Is clue in error?  Perhaps "Slavic State on French north")

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: No, that's probably an error on the creator's part. I noticed it too and meant to address it, but forgot. It's really the south of Spain. Or the "above" of France. `:)`

Comment: Argh, what was I thinking? I think I'll just edit that clue after the fact since the fix is so simple. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, it's not a serious error. Not enough to spoil an otherwise superb thematic cryptic.